# How to display picture in the middle of div?

Tags: html, css

I have created responsive popup and I need to display picture in the middle of div, but when I minimize the screen width, the picture is pinned to the top of div.

[image]

```
     <div class="row">
      <div class="five columns">
       <img class="imga" src="images/warning.png">
      </div>
      <div class="seven columns">
       <p style="color:#e57a2a; font-size: 150%; text-align: center; line-height: 1.1;"><b> siamo spiacenti ma il servizio a domicilio non e al momento disponibile in questa zona </b></p> 
       <p style="color:#20540D; font-size: 120%; text-align: center; line-height: 1.1;"> ti invitiamo ad effettuare l'ordine per il ritiro in negozio presso i nostri ristoranti</p> 
       <center><button style="background-color:#e57a2a;color:white; border:none; height:35px;">ordina ora </button></center>
      </div>
    </div>

.imga{
max-width:100%; 
position: relative;
margin:auto;"
}
```

Comment: please post all the css of the popup, better if you share a fiddle.

Comment: if you can add jsfiddle, we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for cross-browser positioning the image with position relative in the center, you should add:

```
<center>your image</center>
```

Second, the columns class should have a media query class so that it make its position relative, and its display property to be block rather than table-cell.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="five columns">
    <center><img class="imga" src="images/warning.png"></center>
  </div>
  <div class="seven columns">
   <p style="color:#e57a2a; font-size: 150%; text-align: center; line-height: 1.1;"><b> siamo spiacenti ma il servizio a domicilio non e al momento disponibile in questa zona </b></p> 
   <p style="color:#20540D; font-size: 120%; text-align: center; line-height: 1.1;"> ti invitiamo ad effettuare l'ordine per il ritiro in negozio presso i nostri ristoranti</p> 
   <center><button style="background-color:#e57a2a;color:white; border:none; height:35px;">ordina ora </button></center>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
@media all and (max-width:768px){
.columns {
display:block;
position:relative;
}
}
</style>
```

Edit:

Sorry I misunderstood your question.
So mainly you want the information icon to be where it is right now but centered in the middle of its current div:

```
<style>
.columns {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.row {
display:table;
position:absolute;
height:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.imga{
  max-width:100%; 
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

change only margin

Answer (score 0):

Make your columns divs display as table-cell and set vertical align middle

```
.columns{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="five columns">
       <img class="imga" src="images/warning.png">
      </div>
      <div class="seven columns">
       <p style="color:#e57a2a; font-size: 150%; text-align: center; line-height: 1.1;"><b> siamo spiacenti ma il servizio a domicilio non e al momento disponibile in questa zona </b></p> 
       <p style="color:#20540D; font-size: 120%; text-align: center; line-height: 1.1;"> ti invitiamo ad effettuare l'ordine per il ritiro in negozio presso i nostri ristoranti</p> 
       <center><button style="background-color:#e57a2a;color:white; border:none; height:35px;">ordina ora </button></center>
      </div>
    </div>



<style type="text/css">
.imga{
 margin-top:0px auto;
}
  .five{ text-align:center}
</style>
```

Try it

Comment: What is margin-top: 0 auto?